# Yii eager loading — Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: memory, eager-loading, yii

I have a problem with Yii eager loading.
I open user profile page and use:

```
$model=User::model()->with('routes', 'likes', 'comments', 'questions', 'cityname')->findByPk($id);
```

**Relations is:**

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'routes'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Route', 'author_id', 'order'=>'routes.id DESC'),
            'questions'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Question', 'author_id', 'order'=>'questions.id DESC'),
            'comments'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'author_id', 'order'=>'comments.id DESC',),
            'likes'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Like', 'author_id', 'order'=>'likes.id DESC'),
            'cityname'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'City', 'city'),
        );
    }
```

When i have around 70 (or more) comments in Comment table, i have error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 348651520) (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in /home/milk/kolyasya.ru/diplomyii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php on line 516
```

The interesting part of this problem, is if i comment any element of with(), for example:

```
$model=User::model()->with('routes', 'likes', 'comments', /* 'questions' */, 'cityname')->findByPk($id);
```

then all works as it should.

I checked all relations in all models and set ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'), but i can't find a source of the problem.

Maybe I need to use lazy loading?

Comment: Hi.
First, describe goals of this loading. What you will view on result page? Only counters of comments, likes etc.? May be, counters with links for another pages? 
In other words, do you need **content** of user's comments or just **number**?

Comment: I need content, because i have tabs with last comments, routes and etc.
I understand how i can optimize this, but i really interested why it all works if i remove any of related table from with()

Comment: You wouldn't possibly need to display the last 70 comments made by a single user. Hence, it makes sense to redefine your relations and add a limit (say like 20)... That way, you're retrieving only the stuff you need and not things you might not use at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're suffering from exploding number of row combinations. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840562/mysql-left-join-of-three-tables-returns-to-many-rows), it describes the same problem on a smaller scale. Basically, you are running a huge query with multiple one-to-many joins, similar to this:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM `User` `t` 
  LEFT JOIN `Route` routes ON t.id = routes.author_id
  LEFT JOIN `Question` questions ON t.id = questions.author_id
  LEFT JOIN `Comment` comments ON t.id = comments.author_id
  LEFT JOIN `Like` likes ON t.id = likes.author_id
  LEFT JOIN `City` city ON t.city = city.id
  WHERE t.id = :id
  ORDER BY routes.id DESC, questions.id DESC, comments.id DESC, likes.id DESC
```

You can take this query, modify it to `SELECT COUNT(*)` and run it in phpMyAdmin to see how many rows it returns. It will be equal to *the number of routes* multiplied by *the number of questions* multiplied by *the number of comments* multiplied by *the number of likes* created by this user.

---

In this situation, it would be a lot more efficient to fetch each `HAS_MANY` relation in a separate query. [Yii can do that](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-performance):

```php
$model=User::model()
  ->with(array(
     'routes' => array('together' => false),
     'likes' => array('together' => false),
     'comments' => array('together' => false),
     'questions' => array('together' => false),
     'cityname' => array(),
  ))
  ->findByPk($id);
```

If you do so, Yii will instead produce multiple SQL queries with less memory usage, similar to the following:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM `User` `t` 
  LEFT JOIN `City` `city` ON `t`.`city` = `city`.`id`
  WHERE `t`.`id` = :id;

SELECT ... FROM `Route` `routes`
  WHERE `author_id` = :id
  ORDER by `routes`.`id` DESC;

SELECT ... FROM `Question` `questions`
  WHERE `author_id` = :id
  ORDER BY `questions`.`id` DESC;

SELECT ... FROM `Comment` `comments`
  WHERE `author_id` = :id
  ORDER BY `comments`.`id` DESC;

SELECT ... FROM `Like` `likes`
  WHERE `author_id` = :id
  ORDER BY `likes`.`id` DESC;
```

The results will be aggregated and returned to your code just like before.